# Get a list of all state in yii

Tags: php, yii, getstate

This is my code:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($rights); $i++) {
    $this->setState($rights[$i], true);
}
```

Here I am setting the setState dynamically, but I want to get all of states in a list. I did not find any references about this. I only found this:

```
Yii::app()->user->getState('name');
```

But this is not helping me. How can I get a list of all states in yii? thx

Comment: Did you take look at [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/56477-get-user-states/). I think it's the only way to get all state but you will also get useless information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the API of [`CWebUser`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#getState-detail), there's no function for that purpose.

According to the code of `setState`, you can see that it saves the values in a session and that there's no another way of "storing" the used states. (Like an array of all created states)

```
public function setState($key,$value,$defaultValue=null)
{
    $key=$this->getStateKeyPrefix().$key;
    if($value===$defaultValue)
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    else
        $_SESSION[$key]=$value;
}
```

One solution is manually going through all the existing sessions ($_SESSION) but in my opinion it's  not very efficient idea.

Another solution is to have a property/variable (`array`) to hold all the states that you've created and than using a `foreach` loop, use `getState`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the CWebUser [source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.16/framework/web/auth/CWebUser.php), then you will see that 
`getState()` function just looking for a `$_SESSION` key with `stateKeyPrefix`

```
public function getState($key,$defaultValue=null)
    {
        $key=$this->getStateKeyPrefix().$key;
        return isset($_SESSION[$key]) ? $_SESSION[$key] : $defaultValue;
    }
```

You can get the state prefix and all states with following code:

```
$prefix = Yii::app()->user->stateKeyPrefix;
$states = array();
foreach( $_SESSION as $key=>$value ) {
  if( strpos($key, $prefix) === 0 ) {
    states[ substr( $key, strlen( $prefix ) ) ] = $value;
  }
}
```